# how to stop ffdshow dialog from popping before a directdhow application in c ++

Tags: c++, video, directshow, ffdshow

I have written an application to automatically capture an image by the laptop web camera using Direct show api in c++ .It is working well but a ffdshow dialog is popping up before the image is captured.
How to programmatically stop the ffdshow dialog?

Answer (score 0):

ffdshow is annoyingly invading applications with this dialog, so you need to "fix" it on ffdshow side by:

1. deinstalling ffdshow
2. putting your application onto ffdshow exception list to suppress the dialog (via registry)
3. by instruction DriectShow filter graph to not take ffdshow for decoding (via `IAMGraphBuilderCallback`)
4. adding ffdshow to the graph explicitly you should bypass the prompt as well